# Require em um arquivo em uma pasta acima

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, require, requirejs

Vamos supor que eu esteja trabalhando em um arquivo em uma pasta com o seguinte caminho:

`User/workspace/project/assets/COISA.js`

daí,eu decido dar `require` em um arquivo com o seguinte caminho:

`User/workspace/project/CONFIG.json`

Como eu faria pra escrever no `require(  )` o caminho do arquivo??

Ou não dá pra fazer isso eu vou precisar de um outro comando?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tente `const coisa = require('../pasta/coisa.js')`
Ou `const coisa = require('./pasta/coisa.js')`
Ou `const coisa = require('/pasta/coisa.js')`

Comment: FUNCIONOU! :D

const coisa = require('../config.json')

Valeu <3

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).